# RX Best Practice: Select with side-effect or use subscribe?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I convert events (Paging events from buttons) to IObservable and receive the result from a service asynchronously.

As a side effect I have to update a child view. I have two solutions:

1. Side effect in the select:

   ```
       //Converting events to a "stream" of search results.
       IObservable<SearchResult> resultsFromPageChange = Observable.FromEventPattern<EventArgs>(this,
           "PageChangedEvent")
           .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
           .Select(async ev =>
            {
                var input = new SearchResultInput()
                {
                    PageSize = PageSize,
                    PageIndex = PageIndex,
                    SearchOptions = _currentSearchOptions,
                    SearchText = SearchText.Value
                };
                var result = await GetPagedComponents(input);
                //Side effect
                ActivateAttributesView(result.Components.FirstOrDefault());

                return result;
            }).Switch(); //flatten and take most recent.
   ```
2. Do the side effect in the subsribe:

   ```
       //Converting events to a "stream" of search results.
       IObservable<SearchResult> resultsFromPageChange = Observable.FromEventPattern<EventArgs>(this,
           "PageChangedEvent")
           .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
           .Select(async ev =>
           {
               var input = new SearchResultInput()
               {
                   PageSize = PageSize,
                   PageIndex = PageIndex,
                   SearchOptions = _currentSearchOptions,
                   SearchText = SearchText.Value
               };
               return await GetPagedComponents(input);
           }).Switch(); //flatten and take most recent.

       //Do side effect in the subscribe
       resultsFromPageChange.Subscribe(x =>
       {
           if (x != null)
               ActivateAttributesView(x.Components.FirstOrDefault());
       });
   ```

Both methods are working. Which solution should I choose and why?

thx.

Because there is question why this produces values at all, here's the complete code:

```
        //Converting events to a "stream" of search results.
        IObservable<SearchResult> resultsFromPageChange = Observable.FromEventPattern<EventArgs>(this,
            "PageChangedEvent")
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
            .Select(async ev =>
            {

                var input = new SearchResultInput()
                {
                    PageSize = PageSize,
                    PageIndex = PageIndex,
                    SearchOptions = _currentSearchOptions,
                    SearchString = SearchString.Value
                };

                return await SearchComponentsPaged(input);

            }).Switch(); //flatten and take most recent.

        SearchString = new ReactiveProperty<string>(""); //Bound to TextBox.Text 

        //Create a "stream" of search results from a string given by user (SearchString)
        SearchResult = SearchString
            .SetValidateNotifyError(s => _componentDataService.ValidateSearchStringLength(s).Errors)
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
            .Select(async term =>
            {
                var input = new SearchResultInput()
                    {
                        PageSize = PageSize,
                        PageIndex = PageIndex,
                        SearchOptions = _currentSearchOptions,
                        SearchString = term
                    };

                return await SearchComponentsPaged(input);

            })
            .Switch()
            .Merge(resultsFromPageChange) //Merge the result of paging and text changing.  
            .ToReactiveProperty();

        //Update Attributes view
        SearchResult.Subscribe(searchResult =>
        {
            if (searchResult != null)
            {
                ActivateAttributesView(searchResult.Components.FirstOrDefault());
                SearchResult.Value.TotalItemsCount = searchResult.TotalItemsCount;
            }

        });
```

What it actually does is sending a search request to a DB when the search string changes and get paged results OR get another page with the same search string when PageChangedEvent has been received. Does the .Merge(...) a subscription?

Comment: for your first solution, does `ActivateAttributesView` get called if there are no subscriptions?

Comment: hmm, I don't know what exactly you mean with "if there are no subscriptions". What I know is, that with solution 2, I have to explicitly check for null. I don't have to check this with solution 1.

Comment: -- Nevermind, I didn't realize you were using the `Task`-based overload of `Switch`.

Comment: Why would one solution sometimes produce null that you must guard against and the other doesn't?  Also, solution 1 does not actually do anything unless you subscribe to it, even if you provide no callbacks to subscribe (e.g. `.Switch().Subscribe()`), this is because `FromEventPattern` does not actually register an event handler until you subscribe.

Comment: I don't understand why there can be results which are null. I do not subscribe to it. But I merge this "stream" with another one. Is that a subscription? I don't know. I will edit the examples to show more of my actual (working) code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go with your second solution. It is more flexible as different subscribers can choose to have different side effects. It's also separates the concerns, the Rx query generates the data and the subscriber uses the data as he pleases.

Comment: Good point. I will wait a little bit before I accept this answer to see if there are other opinions.

Comment: If you do not have to contort your code greatly to make it side-effect free then go ahead and do it the 2nd way--you will have more flexible/maintainable code.  It is also easier to reason about--requires less hunting to find the code which actually has the side-effect as most developers see `Where` and `Select` and assume it is side-effect free.  They tend to look for the `foreach` (for LINQ) or `Subscribe` (for Rx) to look for the side effects.

Answer (score 1):

It's best practice for select and where to be pure functions (side effect free). It shows the intent much more clearly.

Also, as observables are composable and you might want to use the stream of data again elsewhere, it is best to make the side effects as explicit of possible.